# DynamoDB pagination - last evaluated key is not null on last page

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I'm trying to implement pagination in DynamoDB with the Java SDK.

I have simple data model with a `HashKey` id and a date as `RangeKey`. I want to query for all dates after a given one. This works so far but the problem is the pagination part using the last evaluated key.

When querying the last page, the `lastEvaluatedKey`is not null, it still points to the last item of the last page queried. Another query with this key set as `èxclusiveStartKey` then returns 0 results with a `null` `lastEvaluatedKey`.

My code looks like the following:

```
var query = new DynamoDBQueryExpression<DynamoModel>();
var keyCondition = ImmutableMap.<String, AttributeValue>builder()
        .put(":v_userid", new AttributeValue().withS(userId))
        .put(":v_date", new AttributeValue().withS(date.toString()))
        .build();

if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(lastKey)) {
    query.setExclusiveStartKey(ImmutableMap.<String, AttributeValue>builder()
            .put("userId", new AttributeValue().withS(userId))
            .put("date", new AttributeValue().withS(lastKey)).build());
}

query.withKeyConditionExpression("userId = :v_userid AND date >= :v_date");
query.withExpressionAttributeValues(keyCondition);
query.setLimit(2);

QueryResultPage<DynamoModel> resultPage = mapper.queryPage(DynamoModel.class, query);
```

Does anybody know why the `lastEvaluatedKey` is not null when reaching the last item matching the `KeyCondition`? When I only save items that match the condition, the `LastEvaluatedKey` is null as expected.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is the expected behavior of DynamoDB.

> If `LastEvaluatedKey` is not empty, it does not necessarily mean that there is more data in the result set. The only way to know when you have reached the end of the result set is when `LastEvaluatedKey` is empty. ([source](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html#DDB-Query-response-LastEvaluatedKey))

This is a design decision by AWS. The most likely explanation I can think of is that in order to have a `LastEvaluatedKey` iff there are more items, they would have the keep scanning to find more items, and if you’re using a filter expression, they might have to scan the rest of the partition to determine whether or not there are more items. It’s a choice that helps to minimize the latency of the query (and scan) operation.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Then I have to deal with this behaviour somehow.